# how can I dismiss a PopupWindow and keep the SOFTKEYBOARD onscreen

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-dialogfragment, android-popupwindow

I have a `DialogFragment` which shows a `PopupWindow` once you press certain key (@),

I'd like the back button to dismiss the popupwindow while staying focused on the edittext, so user can keep on writing text, instead of taking the keyboard down.

here's an example [image]

Thanks.

Comment: Probably you will have to make "like a popup window" it shall be part of the window itself and using the design give the "popup" look. take care to locate it in the right place and do not cover the keyboard.

Comment: I'd rather not change the ui elements at the moment.